# How to merge dynamic Mono returning methods

Tags: spring, mono, flux, rector

i have 1 simple interface.

```
public interface Validator{
    public Mono<String> perFormValidation(Employee e);
}
```

and then implemented class with methods.

so how to use mergeWith or any other method to merge these mono returing methods

in my main class i am doing thing like below

```
List<Validator> vals;

    @Autowired
    public ValidatorService(List<Validator> vals) {
        this.vals= vals;
    }
```

however not sure how to proceed further

Comment: I think you meant to tag reactor not rector

Comment: oh yes correct :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end up with a list of validation results you would need a `Flux`. You can convert the list of validators in to a `Flux` and then flatMap it to the validation result like so:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();

Mono<List<String>> validations = Flux.fromIterable(vals)
        .flatMap(validator -> validator.performValidation(employee))
        .collect(toList());
```

Or if you don't want a `Mono<List<String>>` and instead could return a `Flux<String>` since a `Flux` is similar to a list while `Mono` is similar to a single object.

```
Flux<String> validations = Flux.merge(validators.stream()
        .map( validator -> validator.performValidation(employee))
        .collect(toList()));
```